# Is there any battery power consumption benefit if Network Location Provider (vs. GPS) is used?

Tags: android, networking, gps, power-management, location-provider

Is there any real battery power consumption benefit if Network Location Provider (vs. GPS) is used?

I believe there should be some benefit, but since I develop on emulator I can not prove my assumption. Does anyone have the evidence that Network Location Provider consumes less battery power than GPS Location Provider? If yes, could you tell how significant it is?

Thanks!

Comment: GPS takes a fair amount of energy - my phone is getting quite warm when using GPS. The network location provider should only use a little power for network communication. I'd say the difference is quite significant.

Comment: @sstn: Could you please confirm this from your personal Android experience? I am asking just because I'd like to be 100% sure. While the Noah's answer is very good Noah gave an assumption based on his iOS experience.

Comment: @Arhimed : I can confirm from personal experience that using GPS drains the battery on my HTC Desire VERY quickly. For example, when recently using the built-in Navigation app when driving, it took my battery from about 75% charge to completely empty in less than one hour. On the other hand, I can leave wi-fi or mobile internet connection enabled for a whole day and only see a battery drain of perhaps 10-20% even with my email app checking for new emails every 30 minutes.

Comment: @Squonk: thanks for sharing your experience.

Comment: @Arhimed : No problem. I realise you asked the question at the beginning of last year so you may well have gained other knowledge on this. I just happened upon the question and remembered the recent experience - the battery failed just a few km from my destination and I had to stop and ask directions from somebody. I now use an in-car charger when using the Navigation app. :)

Answer (score 4):

The difference is likely extremely significant. GPS hardware uses—relative to other components of the phone—a **lot** of power, which is why phones often get warm when their GPS is active. The network location service, on the other hand, just relies on the cell towers to which the phone is connected anyway (and possibly local wifi networks, though I'm not sure about that), and thus should cause little if any extra power consumption.

Comment: It does use Wifi - if I enable Wifi and it finds my local AP, accuracy is much better than without.

Comment: +1, thanks for the reply! So could you confirm the theory by your personal experience? I am asking just because "should cause" does not sound like "I can confirm based on my experience". :)

Comment: @Arhimed: no problem. I use the speculative language because my experience is all iOS; lacking direct experience with Android's workings, I'm making assumptions based on how the corresponding stuff works there.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced significant battery drain while having GPS location turned on vs having it turned off on my Android phone.  I always leave it off, except when I actually need it for traveling as a GPS.  But then my phone won't last all day, like it will without using GPS.